# RavenDB LINQ query against index fails

Tags: linq, indexing, ravendb

I get the following error when trying to run a specific query against RavenDB:

`Can't extract value from expression of type: ArrayIndex`

Here is the query that is generating the error:

```
people = from p in RavenSession.Query<DBObjects.Person, People_ByNameAndTrashedSortByFirstNameAndLastName>()
         orderby p.FirstName, p.LastName
         select p;
...
//building LINQ query
...
people = from p in people
         where ((p.FirstName.StartsWith(SearchWords[0])) && (p.LastName.StartsWith(SearchWords[1])))
         select p;
...
//later
foreach(DBObject.Person person in people)  //triggers error listed above
{
}
```

I'm wondering if this is a limitation of RavenDB.  I noticed that if I switch `&&` with `||`, then I get no error.  Of course, I don't get the results I want either.  I've also tried rewriting the query as:

```
people = from p in people
         where p.FirstName.StartsWith(SearchWords[0])
         where p.LastName.StartsWith(SearchWords[1])
         select p;
```

I get the same error.
I've also tried using a dynamic index instead of a static index.  I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose maybe RavenDB LINQ driver cannot cope with extracting value from array inside the query. Try to put already extracted values in the place of `SearchWords[0]` and `SearchWords[1]` instead:

```
var pref1 = SearchWords[0];
var pref2 = SearchWords[1];
... where ( p.FirstName.StartsWith(pref1) && p.LastName.StartsWith(pref2) )
```

Comment: That was it.  It turns out the reason it worked as `||` instead of `&&` was because I was searching for the whole input text instead of the split out words in an array.  Thanks!

Comment: Argh! Hit the same issue. Tripped up again by something the RavenDB LINQ driver doesn't support. Thank you!